# How to append values from HTML to jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, here is my `HTML` code and `jQuery` code. I want to pass the value attribute to jQuery so that I can use it as an parameter for my `if else` loop but I am unable to do so. Here is my sample code.

HTML Code:

```
<select id="counting" class="normal_button">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">value  type</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
   <option value="4">Four</option>  
</select>
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#counting").click(function(){
        if (value == "1") 
        {
            jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Test</p>");
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Tests</p>");        
        }
    });
});
```

So here I want that if the options change then the text appended also changes hence I have used value as my parameter for if condition. Also I am appending text to another `div` text area, is that fine? Can I do that?

I am new to this so please help me. It's showing me the error value is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#counting").bind("change", function(){
          if ($(this).val() == "1") 
          {
               jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Test</p>");
          }
          else {
               jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Tests</p>");        
          }
     }); 
 });
```

I just made 2 changes -

1) used `bind("change"),` instead of `click` and

2) used `$(this).val()` instead of `value`.

Comment: i cant see any error but i also can't see the appended item

Comment: check if you have a div or something similar with id = text_area. Here's a fiddle that shows it working Cheers! Note that you have to change the select box to make it do something.

Comment: what do you mean by change the select box

Comment: select a value in the select box to trigger the change event.

Comment: like can you pleas elaborate i am new to this

Comment: Oops - I realized I hadn't attached the fiddle. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/4rw0x48u/. Change the dropdown to Four , one...

Comment: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

i am getting this error.. i thinkbecause of this ".this" is not being passed and i am getting no output

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand - is this something you are seeing when you run the fiddle?

Comment: can you write an example event trigger as you explained earlier for me to have a look at and understand

Answer (score 0):

when you have select boxes and you want something happen on selecting that selectbox, you can not use *.click* function. *.click* function is for when something is clicked. but here you select. so first of all you should use *.change* function.

and when you want to have value of selected select box, *value* variable is not exist by itself. you should use *$(this).val()*.

*$this* is your select box which you select something from it,and *$(this).val()* returning the selected value.

here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OyAXGfUFEFkl9s9SMlHC?p=preview)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("#counting").change(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == "1") 
      {
          jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Test</p>");
      }
      else {
          jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Tests</p>");        
      }
   });
  });
```

Comment: i am not able to view text output in the text area

Comment: @kamehamehaaaaaa where is your text area? in plunker I created there is a text area and you can see text output there

Comment: @kamehamehaaaaaa do you have any `div` in your `HTML` with `id="text_area"` ? cause you should have one ;)

Comment: ya i have a div which is basically named text_area where i see the results

Comment: @kamehamehaaaaaa no, your `div` should have `id="text_area"` not named text_area

Comment: `<div id="text_area"></div>`   like this,do have this in your `HTML`?

Comment: yes i do have a div like that. i am also getting a message. Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. is it possible ".this" is not working

Comment: I actually have no other Ideas,sorry, try putting your html and js file in http://plnkr.co or some other site for us to see what is causing you problem.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(this).val()` would give the value of selected option. This needs to be binded on selection change event.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#counting').change(function() {
    value = jQuery(this).val();
    if (value == "1") {
      jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Test</p>");
    } else {
      jQuery("#text_area").append("<p>Tests</p>");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="counting" class="normal_button">
  <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">value type</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
  <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<div id="text_area">

</div>
```